# Determining $B^{\mathrm{o}},\partial B,B'$ for $B=b_n=\{-1-\frac{6n}{n^2-10},n\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\} \}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory

As title suggests, I have $B=b_n=\{-1-\frac{6n}{n^2-10},n\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\} \}$ and have to determine  $B^{\mathrm{o}},\partial B,B'$ (i.e. sets of interior,boundary and accumulation points,respectively).
To start with, if we take function assosicated to set it is obvious that we have a pair of vertical asymptotes at $x=\sqrt 10$.
$b(x)\to -\infty$ for $x\to {\sqrt 10}^+$ and $b(x)\to +\infty$ for $x\to{\sqrt 10}^-$.Taking derivative $$b'(x)=\frac{6(x^2+10)}{(x^2-10)^2}\gt0$$ We find out that function is monotone increasing.
$3\lt\sqrt 10\lt4$ so on the left of $\sqrt 10$, we are considering $n\in[0,3]$,which gives us $\max b_n=17$ and on the right we are approaching $-1$,with $\min b_n=-5$.
As for the sets, I think $B'$ might equal to $\{-1\}$ because our set gets denser as we approach -1.I am clueless about the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interior is empty since no open set is contained in $B$ (in particular, no point can have a neighbourhood contained in $B$).

Moreover, all points in the set are isolated. In particular, neighbourhoods of a point will always contain points outside of $B$, so all points are on the boundary. Adding the limit point, you get $\partial B = B \cup \{-1\} = B$.

Finally, since all points in $B$ are isolated, except  $-1$, they cannot be limit points, making -1 the only one.

Comment: You mean, making -1 only accumulation point,right?

Comment: accumulation point and limit point typically mean the same thing. also we know the interior is empty since $B \subset \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Yes, I meant accumulation point with limit point. Also, I've noticed now that $-1 \in B$, so the boundary is simply $B$.